# В чём отличие вызова функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

Прошу помочь разобраться.

У функции **goCount** есть ссылка не лексическое окружение - глобальное окружение, в котором находятся переменные:
**result: 0**,
**goCount: function**,
**counter: function**.

Переменной **counter** присваивается результат работы функции, т.е. возвращается увеличенное значение переменной - **1**. И каждый последующий раз возвращается одно и то же значение - **1**.
Почему значение не увеличивается дальше?

```
    // ПЕРВЫЙ ПРИМЕР
    let result = 0;
    
    function goCount() {   
      return ++result
    }
    
    // переменной присваивается результат функции
    let counter = goCount(); 
    
    counter; // 1
    counter; // 1
    counter; // 1
    
    console.log(result) // 1
```

А вот, если убрать переменную **counter** и вызывать непосредственно саму функцию, тогда предыдущее значение функция запоминает:

```
// ВТОРОЙ ПРИМЕР
let result = 0;

    function goCount() {   
      return ++result
    }

    
    goCount(); // 1
    goCount(); // 2
    goCount(); // 3        


    console.log(result) // 3
```

Выходит, что причина в переменной **counter**.
Что происходит, когда вызываем результат функции через эту переменную? Из-за чего именно всегда результат один и тот же?

---

Есть предположение, что из-за того, что переменной **counter** присваивается именно значение, то после того, как функция завершила свою работу - глобальное окружение удаляется, и при следующем вызове функции глобальное окружение рождается с начальными параметрами. А вот, если переменной присвоить именно ссылку на функцию:

```
    // ТРЕТИЙ ПРИМЕР (равнозначен ВТОРОМУ)
    let counter = goCount; // присваивается ссылка на функцию
    
    counter(); // 1
    counter(); // 2
    counter(); // 3
```

...тогда глобальное окружение не сбрасывается, после завершения работы функции, поскольку в переменной есть функция, которая запомнила глобальное лексическое окружение, следовательно - результат работы функции (первый пример) в себе этого не хранит, поэтому и результат всегда один и тот же.

Comment: Переменной count в вашем коде не существует. Увеличиваете count и из функции возвращаете count переменная result как была со значением 0 так и остаётся вы с ней ничего не делаете.

Comment: глобальное окружение на то и глобальное, что никогда не сбрасывается.

Comment: @Grundy читай mozdoc! let и var!!!

Comment: @EugeneX, и какая связь let и var с тем, что спрашивается в вопросе? и с глобальным окружением? :)

Comment: @Tew ну так в первом примере в переменной counter результат функции, во втором  происходит вызов функции 3 раза и третьем ссылка на функцию, которую потом 3 раза вызываешь.

Comment: @Tew 1. решение надо было публиковать как ответ, а не правку вопроса. 2. ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а где решение опубликовано?

Comment: @Grundy, в правках было предложено. я отклонил эту правку.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном коде, значение `result` изменяется только при вызове функции.

В первом варианте функция вызывается один раз. Значение изменилось один раз.

Во втором и третьем - функция вызвалась три раза. Значение изменилось три раза.

Непонятно, почему в первом варианте, ожидалось, что значение дополнительно поменяется само по себе.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131527/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-----).

Answer (score -1):

```js
 let result = 0; // result = 0
    
    function goCount() {
      return ++result // вернуть result увеличить его на 1
    }
    
    let counter = goCount(); // вызвать goCount и ref на него, увеличили на 1
   
    counter; // работаем с референсом result который был увеличен на 1
    counter; // нечего не поменялось не с референсом не с переменной
    counter; // нечего не поменялось не с референсом не с переменной
    
    console.log(result) // выводим result который был равен 1 после вызова goCount
```

То-есть при переменная = переменная по сути ты же сам дал reference на result, который ты не меняешь. Ты же используешь let который имеет оптимизацию по референсам.

Так-же само во втором примере... Ты используешь в результате reference на result

=== Добавлено после комментария @Grundy ===

Какая к чёрту глобальная переменная... Ссылка (знак равно) на переменную в let становиться reference переменной вот хардкод с консоли. При чём там глобальные?!

```
let x = 1;
>> undefined
function incX() { x += 1 };
>> undefined
incX();
>> undefined
x
>> 2
```

=== Добавлено после обсуждений с @Grundy ===

Спасибо Grundy, за тыканье пальцем в слепого.

После обсуждений в чате, явно ошибка программирования находиться в 30 сантиметров от монитора.

```
   // ПЕРВЫЙ ПРИМЕР
    let result = 0;
    
    function goCount() {   
      return ++result // увеличить result на 1 и вернуть (выполнение) в return
    }

    let counter = goCount(); // тут после вызова результат 1
    
    counter; // counter не меняется равен 1
    counter; // counter не меняется
    counter; // counter не меняется
    
    console.log(result) // result не меняется равен 1
```

В этом примере

```
// ВТОРОЙ ПРИМЕР
let result = 0;

    function goCount() {   
      return ++result  // Увеличить результат на 1 и вернуть (выполнение) в ретурн
    }

    
    goCount(); // 1   (Увеличил и вернул на 1 больше)
    goCount(); // 2   (Увеличил и вернул на 1 больше)
    goCount(); // 3   (Увеличил и вернул на 1 больше)


    console.log(result) // 3   (Естественно он равен 3, ибо ты его три раза через ++ прогнал
```

Автору вопроса....

```js
let x = 1;
console.log(++x);
> 2 // Потому что ты сначала добавил 1 к X потом вывел на экран
console.log(x++);
> 2 // Потому что ты начало вернул результат, потом вывел X на экран
x === 2 (true) потому что после того как ты вывел, ты увеличил.
```

Comment: "Глобальное окружение" - это в самом низу моего поста, моё предположение. Если первый вызов "counter" увеличил переменную, то по логике и последующие вызовы должны её увеличить, но этого не происходит, а возвращается предыдущий результат, хотя второй и третий вызовы ничем не отличаются от первого. Тем не менее, первый вызов увеличил, а второй и третий нет. Вот собственно, в различие? :-)

Comment: @Tew. ты ошибся с термином "вызов". В этом основная проблема у тебя.